# If-else to control button event

Tags: android, if-statement

Here I connected the laptop and android through bluetooth.

My question is , how can I set a data when I don't push the button.

My android application sends +,- when I press +button and - button.

If I press + button, the program in laptop increase the value, and - button gives opposite result.

But what I need is one by one change in value.

That means, one click increase the value in one time, not continuously increasing the value.

The code below sends the data which pushed in the last when i don't push the button.

```
 package remote.bluetooth;





import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MouseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    int score = 0;
    TextView Value;
    Button Plus, Minus;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mouseactivity);

        Plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RClick);
        Minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LClick);

        Value = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);

        Plus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        Minus.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        //왼 클릭 버튼 생성 및 이벤트 연결     
       }


public void onClick(View v)
{

if(v.getId()==R.id.RClick)
{
    String msg = "+";

    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

    score++;
    Value.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
else if (v.getId()==R.id.LClick)
{
    String msg = "-";

    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

    score--;
    Value.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
else
{
    String msg = "0";

    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

}}
}
```

and the send message method

```
 public void sendMessage(String mMsg) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mConnection.getState() != BluetoothConnection.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (mMsg.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = mMsg.getBytes();
            mConnection.write(send);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are incrementing the value twice in code. Once in the switch statement and then again in the if-else sequence. I'm thinking you only want to do that in one spot.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing and decrementing your `score` variable twice.

Here:

```
case R.id.RClick: score++; showText = true; break;
```

And Here:

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.RClick){
    String msg = "+";

    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

    score++;
    Value.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
```

Comment: well, I changed the code lol, it still doesn't stop to change value

Comment: public void sendMessage(String mMsg) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mConnection.getState() != BluetoothConnection.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (mMsg.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = mMsg.getBytes();
            mConnection.write(send);
        }
    }

Comment: I don't quite understand your question though :/ what do you mean by `how can I set a data when I don't push the button.` and `The code below sends the data which pushed in the last when i don't push the button.`?

Comment: hmm. When I push + button --> the value increase in my laptop!. But while i don't push any buttons, the string is still remaining +.Then the value in laptop keep increasing. So I want to change the + value to any other value.

Comment: Rather than sending a '+' command using an OnClick, you can use an OnTouch to send a '+' command onKeyDown and a 'keyup' command onKeyUp!

Comment: I think keyup event is only for keyboard right? I'm controlling the android application

Comment: Android has a onTouchListener, you can check whether the key is pressed or released: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: Hmm then if i use Ontouch to send + command, then it sends the command only one time?

Comment: Button LClickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LClick);
        LClickButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_UP) {
      LClick();
    }
    return false; 
   }

   private void LClick() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String msg = "-";
   
    Main.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
    
    score--;
    Value.setText(String.valueOf(score));
   }       
        });

Comment: Well you need to also send a command onKeyUp that tells your laptop that it needs to release the '+' command

Comment: oh nono lol I don't need to change that statement . It works well but what I need is initializing the value